# Propriedade color no css não funcionando no Safari de IOS

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma `<div>` com uma tag `<p>` contendo um número de telefone. No CSS tenho a propriedade com `color: #000`. Porém, só no Safari, não está funcionando. O telefone fica com a cor branca.

É como o Safari estivesse colocando a cor por si próprio.

Comment: Tente colocar color: #000!important, ou color: black!important;

Comment: Joao Paulo, já tentei e não funcionou.

Comment: Colocando direto na tag style do elemento funciona? Mesmo que não seja a solução já da alguma pista.

Comment: posta o seu html e css, fica mais fácil ajuda-lo. Nota: ao fazer referência a um utilizador, coloque o @ (arroba) antes do nome, ao pressionar o arroba vai aparecer uma caixinha com o nome do utilizador, seleccione. Assim o utilizador recebe uma notificação e não se esquece do post.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @Filipe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso muito provavelmente se dá devido ao fato de a maioria dos sistemas operacionais móveis identificarem automaticamente números de telefone e criarem um *link* deles com o discador do smartphone a fim de "facilitar" a vida do usuário.

Para remover essa funcionalidade nos browsers / webviews, existem basicamente duas soluções:

### Solução 1: Uso ta metatag `format-detection`:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Isso previne que dentro da página HTML em questão números de telefone sejam "convertidos".

### Solução 2: Truque utilizando elementos `inline`:

```
<!-- Poderia ser qualquer elemento inline -->
<span>9911-</span><span>2233</span>
```

Separando o telefone em vários elementos dificulta a vida do algorítimo que identifica os números, fazendo com que eles não sejam identificados e consequentemente alterados.

Comment: Valeu, cara. Usei a metatag e funcionou!

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas @kazzkiq! Tive o mesmo problema que o @lucas e utilizei o truque dos elementos inline. Funcionou que foi uma maravilha! Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Usei uma solução apresentada aqui e outra de outro fórum e resolvi o problema.

O Safari não reconhece o css por causa da função "discador". 
O Chrome reconhece o css

Se usar a metatag aqui proposta, o site perderia em usabilidade já que clientes teriam que copiar ou memorizar o número para ligar

Então fiz o seguinte:
Usei a metatag proposta aqui: `<meta name format-detection" content="telephone=no">` (obrigado, boa dica)

E coloquei um HREF no telefone: `<a href="tel:1130693939>`. No meu caso, era em PHP, e foi com parenteses traços e tudo mais, mas os discadores limpam isso.

Ou seja, enganei o chrome no android e no safari. Estilizou certinho e não perdeu a função de discador.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz seguinte forma e funcionou:

HTML

```
<span>(99) 9999-9999</span>
```

CSS

```
span {color:#000000;}
span a {color:#000000;}
```

Mesmo que não exista o `<a>` no HTML eu considerei como se ele existisse no css. Aqui funcionou de boa.